# Unassigned value / Console Readline

Tags: c#

I am new to c# and I have an issue in my code. My description is unassigned, however my title that I am assigning in the same way is ok and runs fine. Could you please explain to me how is that possible? I do apologise if this is a duplicate I have tried to read several post but couldn't find any posts matching.

```
namespace ExercisePost
{
    public class Post
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public DateTime CretationTime { get; set; }


        public void SetTitle()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please, enter the title to your post ");

        }
        public void SetDescription()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please, enter the body to your post " );

        }
        public DateTime Publication()
        {
            CretationTime = DateTime.Now;
            return CretationTime;
        }


    }
    class Program
    {
       public static void  Main(string[] args)
       {
           var post = new Post();

            Console.WriteLine("Wanna share a post? If so please pres 'y' otherwise any key to cancel");


            while(true)
            {
                var input = Console.ReadLine();
                if (input == "y")
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    post.SetTitle();
                    string title = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(title))
                    {
                        post.SetTitle();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       post.SetDescription();
                       string description = Console.ReadLine();

                    }
                    Console.WriteLine( title + description );
                }
                else 
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("GoodBye");
                    break;
                }
            }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code should not even compile...

Answer (score 1):

Please, declare the description variable at the beginning of the function and not in the if like this :

```
public static void  Main(string[] args)
       {
           var post = new Post();
           string description = "";      // variable declaration

            Console.WriteLine("Wanna share a post? If so please pres 'y' otherwise any key to cancel");


            while(true)
            {
                var input = Console.ReadLine();
                if (input == "y")
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    post.SetTitle();
                    string title = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(title))
                    {
                        post.SetTitle();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       post.SetDescription();
                       description = Console.ReadLine(); // variable assignment

                    }
                    Console.WriteLine( title + description );
                }
                else 
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("GoodBye");
                    break;
                }
            }
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize an object , it executes class's default constructor that assign default values (`null`) in this case. your description has null value that's why your code ran fine.